# javascript_include_tag params[:controller] does not work in production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I wish to implement controller specific js file so I used the following code and made sure require_tree is removed from app.js.

```
javascript_include_tag params[:controller]
```

Because according to this from the [asset pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html):

```
You can also opt to include controller specific stylesheets and JavaScript files only in their respective controllers using the following:

<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %> or <%= stylesheet_link_tag
params[:controller] %>

When doing this, ensure you are not using the require_tree directive, as that will result in your assets being included more than once.
```

**BUT** in production, the resulting code is simply `<script src="/javascripts/main_page.js"></script>` instead of using the precompiled name like `main_page_12basdabsd123a.js` and causing that js file fail to load.

May I ask where i am missing here and how to solve this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Did you precompile your js by writing `config.assets.precompile += %w( main_page.js )` in production.rb?